# How to view the installed Firefox OS web apps on a desktop?

Tags: firefox, firefox-os

I had installed several web apps from the [Firefox Marketplace](https://marketplace.firefox.com/popular) for desktop.

How to list all the installed apps?

I am using Linux on a XFCE4 machine.

Comment: In WebIDE select *localRuntime*, then select *Open App*; the list is inside *Runtime Apps*. WebIDE its present in new versions, disabled by default, see [WebIDE info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/WebIDE).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, they appear under the "Other" entry on the XFCE4 menu.